# Why the actual string is not shown in recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hi guys I am trying to create a **To Do List** android application.
There is is `recyclerView` can be dynamically added. I attach a Floating Action Button to my layout. when press the fab it shows a dialog box. The dialog box contain a `EditText` and a Done Button. When the done button is pressed the value in the `editText` is give to the recycler. I use setters and *getters* to allocate data to *recycler*.

**My problem** : The *recycler* not show the String type text it show the other data like

[image]

**HomeFragment class**

```
package com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data.CRUD;
import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data.SpaceCraft;
import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data.SpaceCraftCollection;
import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.recycler.MyAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    FloatingActionButton mFab;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    CRUD mCRUD;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mCRUD = new CRUD(SpaceCraftCollection.getSpaceCrafts());
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mCRUD.getSpaceCrafts());

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                displayDialog();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    //Add Data
    //Show Dialog
    private  void  displayDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle("Add New Group");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editField);
        Button done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SpaceCraft s = new SpaceCraft();
                s.setTitle(editText.toString());

                if (mCRUD.addNew(s)) {

                    editText.setText("");

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

}
```

**MyAdapter class**

```
package com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.recycler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.R;
import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data.SpaceCraft;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<SpaceCraft> mSpaceCrafts;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SpaceCraft> spaceCrafts) {
        mContext = context;
        mSpaceCrafts = spaceCrafts;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        final String title =  mSpaceCrafts.get(position).getTitle();

        //BIND
        holder.groupTitle.setText(title);

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos) {
                //do click stuff here
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSpaceCrafts.size();
    }
}
```

**MyHolder class**

```
package com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.recycler;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.R;

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView groupTitle;
    ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        groupTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.groupTitle);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {

        this.mItemClickListener = itemClickListener;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        this.mItemClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition());
    }
}
```

**CRUD class**

```
package com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CRUD {

    ArrayList<SpaceCraft> mSpaceCrafts;

    public CRUD(ArrayList<SpaceCraft> spaceCrafts) {
        mSpaceCrafts = spaceCrafts;
    }

    //ADD
    public boolean addNew(SpaceCraft spaceCraft) {
        try {

            mSpaceCrafts.add(spaceCraft);

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return false;
    }

    //Retrieve
    public ArrayList<SpaceCraft> getSpaceCrafts() {

        return mSpaceCrafts;
    }

    //Update
    public boolean update(int position, SpaceCraft newSpaceCraft) {
        try {

            mSpaceCrafts.remove(position);
            mSpaceCrafts.add(position, newSpaceCraft);

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return false;
    }

    //Delete
    public boolean delete(int pos) {
        try {

            mSpaceCrafts.remove(pos);

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return false;

    }


}
```

**SpaceCraft class**

```
package com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data;

public class SpaceCraft {

    String mTitle;

    public SpaceCraft() {}

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
}
```

**SpaceCraftCollection class**

```
package com.example.app.wounderlist.todolist.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SpaceCraftCollection {

    //create a array list using the SpaceCraft model
    static ArrayList<SpaceCraft> spaceCrafts = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<SpaceCraft> getSpaceCrafts() {

        return spaceCrafts;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is culprit, you forgot `getText()` on `Edittext`

```
SpaceCraft s = new SpaceCraft();
                s.setTitle(editText.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a text from `EditText`, you need to call `getText()`. So, your code should looks like

```
SpaceCraft s = new SpaceCraft();
s.setTitle(editText.getText().toString());
```